# capture end of line string but avoid capturing matching trailing characters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following lines, more or less:

```
$strings = [
  "Concepto de la transferencia    Un concepto uno        ",
  "Concepto traspaso    Orden #121231",
  "Concepto trasnferencia       121231 Magical Concept      ",
 ]
```

And have the following regex:

```
|Concepto\s+(?>de la )?(?>tr.+erencia|traspaso)\s+(?P<concepto>.+)$|
```

Which nicely captures the end-part of each of these strings:

```
  "Un concepto uno        "
  "Orden #121231"
  "121231 Magical Concept       "
```

(trailing spaces included). But I'd like the match to **exclude** the trailing spaces, when they exist. Resulting in:

```
  "Un concepto uno"
  "Orden #121231"
  "121231 Magical Concept"
```

I've tried:

```
Concepto\s+(?>de la )?(?>tr.+erencia|traspaso)\s+(?P<concepto>.+)(?>\s+)?$
```

or

```
Concepto\s+(?>de la )?(?>tr.+erencia|traspaso)\s+(?P<concepto>.+)\s*$
```

But neither work, obviously. Can't make inline modifiers E.g. (`U`) work for the `concepto` group.

And I know I cant just `trim` the resulting match and be done with it. Just want to make this regex work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, turn the last `.+` into `.+?` (use lazy quantifier) and add `\s*` before `$`:

```
Concepto\s+(?>de la )?(?>tr.+erencia|traspaso)\s+(?P<concepto>.+?)\s*$
                                                                ^ ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQCmt0/1)

If the "concepto" group can be empty, replace `.+?` with `.*?`. Since `*?` / `+?` are lazy, the `\s*` will be tested against first, and thus all the trailing whitespace symbols will be outside "concepto" group.

Also, the atomic groups (`(?>)`) here can be replaced with mere non-capturing (`(?:)`) groups.

Comment: The faster you answer, the dumber I feel. :P Thanks a lot :)